# Bootstrap Modal only displaying once when I use a bindingHandler

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

**JSFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/PTSkR/177/

**Desired behavior:** When I click close or the x button, the modal closes, but I can still open it again if I click "show".

**What's happening**: The modal closes one time and then never opens again.

**Code**:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.showModal = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = valueAccessor();
        if (ko.utils.unwrapObservable(value)) {
            $(element).modal('show');
                                // this is to focus input field inside dialog
            $("input", element).focus();
        }
        else {
            $(element).modal('hide');
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will want to make sure that you handle the `hidden` event of the modal, so that you can clear your observable.  Then, the next time that you set it to `true`, it will notify any subscribers since it actually changed (observables don't notify when their value is set to the same value).

Something like this in your init:

```
    init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        $(element).on("hidden", function() {
            valueAccessor()(false); 
        });
    },
```

If necessary, you can use `ko.isWriteableObservable` to determine if the value passed into the binding is actually an observable that you can write to.